# Express doen not load javascript to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, requirejs

I want to use requireJS for client code. My file structure is:

```
ProjectRoot
 |-server.js
 |-public/
    |-index.html
    |-js/
       |-app.js
       |-lib/
          |-require.min.js
          |-underscore.js
          |-backbone.js
          |-raphael.js
       |-app/
          |-..
```

*server.js:*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8090);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="js/lib/require.min.js" data-main="js/app.js" />
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
        'raphael': 'lib/raphael'
    },
    shim: {
        'lib/underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'lib/backbone': {
            deps: ["lib/underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

**Problem:** When I go to `localhost:8090` I get only `index.html` without any .js file

**Question:** why Express does not send javascript to the client?

**P.S.** But when I go to `http://localhost:8090/js/app.js` I get my `app.js`

Also I launch my app with `node server.js` command

**Problem 2:** My app cannot load `data-main` file. Instead of requesting `localhost:8090/js/app.js` it asks for `localhost:8090/js/app.app`. Why app.app?

Comment: Have you looked into Browserify? It will save you some time and boilerplate.

Comment: @elclanrs is that an alternative to requirejs? I don't want to give up because of such stupid bug ) Hope you'll help me

Comment: @elclanrs the problem is that express doesn't send `require.min.js` to the client. I think that's the reason why it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried watching the network tab in chrome dev tools or Firebug in FF when loading your page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) I'm not guessing, I replicated your environment here and with the self closing tag nothing loads but if I change it to `<script...></script>` then it works.

Comment: @Louis you solve my problem! Thanks!!

Comment: @Louis get the next problem - my app can't fine `data-main` file.  I loaded demo to https://github.com/JOLO-/NodeApp

Comment: @V_B You should post a new question. The community has already responded to the question you first asked. Now you're asking a different problem. Sure it is still that your code won't load but the 1st issue was an HTML one whereas now it seems to be a RequireJS issue. It's called a ["chameleon question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/241526). I glanced at the off-site code and see some config differences that are pertinent to your problem. The question you post on SO must contain all the pertinent information in the *body of the question itself*.

Comment: @V_B Oh, and don't put the `.js` extension in the names of your modules when you tell RequireJS to load them. `data-main` contains the name of a module. So no extension there. I don't know whether this has any bearing on your problem. RequireJS will accept a module name with `.js` but this changes the rules it then follows for path resolution and since I *never* put `.js` in module names I don't remember how RequireJS behaves when there is a `.js` extension in a module name.

Comment: @V_B And now I see you have posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26816008/1906307) before I posted my comment above about doing just this. All the more reason to delete this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is in static module, your nodejs code should be like that:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8090);
```

The issue in:

**Q1:**
I think the issue may be from empty content model, so please try to use

```
 <script></script>
```

instead of

```
<script />
```

**Q2:**
I think this is an issue in require.js version, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816008/requirejs-search-for-app-app-instead-of-app-js-where-app-js-is-entry-point-spec) for more info.

Comment: @HazenHagrass look pls at problem 2 section of my quesiton

Comment: @HazenHagrass it still looks for `main.app`. Look pls at https://github.com/JOLO-/NodeApp

Comment: @V_B why you are adding this app.use('js/app.app', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js/app.js')); it is not correct, I think you should remove this line

Comment: I tried. That doesn't work anyway. Just accidentally pushed it

Comment: I attached a link in my answer about Q2, I'm sure it will solve your issue.

Comment: run RequireJS API ref?) I've read it, but seems I'm missing smth

Comment: you could see the answer to the second question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816008/requirejs-search-for-app-app-instead-of-app-js-where-app-js-is-entry-point-spec. Modify your answer due it please