# RequireJS search for app.app instead of app.js (where app.js is entry point specified in data-main)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, requirejs

**Problem:**

I have a trivial demo application which use requireJS. When `require.min.js`  script loads, it tries to load entry-point script. But, the **Problem** is that instead of `localhost:8090/js/app.js` it tries to load `localhost:8090/js/app.app` and fails.

**Demo:** You can see the whole app at [GitHub](https://github.com/JOLO-/NodeApp).

**=== Only if you don't like GutHub, here's my code ===**

*File structure*

```
ProjectRoot
 |-server.js
 |-public/
    |-index.html
    |-js/
       |-app.js
       |-lib/
          |-require.min.js
          |-underscore.js
          |-backbone.js
          |-raphael.js
       |-app/
          |-..
```

*server.js:*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8090);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="js/lib/require.min.js" data-main="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
        'raphael': 'lib/raphael'
    },
    shim: {
        'lib/underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'lib/backbone': {
            deps: ["lib/underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your version of require.js included in the app. Use the CDN one and it works.

The version you have in your code does not match the actual .min version on the CDN which means it was modified and includes `.app`

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
```